# AngularJS Typeahead with structured values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I have a working typeahead element taken from the example in [here](https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv), very simple and works perfectly.

Now, my problem is that the data I need to handle has in fact two data elements, something like `{"Index":"<Index>","Value":"<Name>"}`.

I need to present within the list a string like `<index> - <Name>`, allow the user to type either any combination including parts of the Index and/or Value and, upon selection, keep only the Index (this is the only **unique** part of the list).

I modified the list in the above mentioned example to:

```
var States = JSON.parse('[{"Index":"1","Value":"Alabama"},      ' +
                        '{"Index":"2","Value":"Alaska"},        ' +
                        '{"Index":"3","Value":"Arizona"},       ' +
                        '{"Index":"4","Value":"Arkansas"},      ' +
                        '{"Index":"5","Value":"California"},    ' +
                        '{"Index":"6","Value":"Colorado"},      ' +
                        '{"Index":"7","Value":"Connecticut"},   ' +   
                        '{"Index":"8","Value":"Delaware"},      ' +
                        '{"Index":"9","Value":"Florida"},       ' +
                        '{"Index":"10","Value":"Georgia"},      ' +
                        '{"Index":"11","Value":"Hawaii"},       ' +
                        '{"Index":"12","Value":"Idaho"},        ' +
                        '{"Index":"13","Value":"Illinois"}]     '   ) ;
```

and set the HTML to:

```
        <input name="states" 
               id="states" 
               type="text" 
               placeholder="enter a state" 
               ng-model="selected" 
               value="(state.Index)" 
               typeahead="(state.Value) for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
               class="form-control">
```

which is not doing the job.

To summarize, entries in the typeahead list should look like:

```
1 - Alabama
2 - Alaska
...
```

and when the user selects an entry (say the first one), the value received within the script should be "1" (and not "1 - Alabama").

### Edit

I implemented ONE-TO-ONE the code suggested by tanmay below and, somehow, it is not working for me. Instead of getting (for instance) `6 - Colorado` I get only a `-`, meaning no number (index) nor State name. Interestingly, the number of options shown do match what I typed (meaning, if I enter `m` I get only ne record with `-` which would correspond to **Alabama**).

Here are the whole HTML and JS files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="with=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">

        <title>MyTest - Partial</title>
        <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="Public_Libs/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Public_Libs/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular-ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="Index_Controller.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="angularTypeahead">
          <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
            <a>
                <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label.Index | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>   - 
                <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label.Value | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>   
            </a>
          </script>
          <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
              <h2><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo"> Angular.js Typeahead</h2>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="states">Search for US States</label>
                  <input name="states" id="states" type="text" 
                         typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"
                         placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" 
                         typeahead="state.Index as state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
                         class="form-control">
              </div>
              <pre>{{selected}}</pre>
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// https://angular-ui.github.io/

// setup app and pass ui.bootstrap as dep
var myApp = angular.module("angularTypeahead", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

// define factory for data source
  myApp.factory("States", function() {
    var states = JSON.parse('[{"Index":"1","Value":"Alabama"},      ' +
                          '{"Index":"2","Value":"Alaska"},        ' +
                          '{"Index":"3","Value":"Arizona"},       ' +
                          '{"Index":"4","Value":"Arkansas"},      ' +
                          '{"Index":"5","Value":"California"},    ' +
                          '{"Index":"6","Value":"Colorado"},      ' +
                          '{"Index":"7","Value":"Connecticut"},   ' +   
                          '{"Index":"8","Value":"Delaware"},      ' +
                          '{"Index":"9","Value":"Florida"},       ' +
                          '{"Index":"10","Value":"Georgia"},      ' +
                          '{"Index":"11","Value":"Hawaii"},       ' +
                          '{"Index":"12","Value":"Idaho"},        ' +
                          '{"Index":"13","Value":"Illinois"}]     '   ) ;

    return states;

});

// setup controller and pass data source
myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope, States) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;

  $scope.states = States;

});
```

How could I copy the code of the example (see link in tanmay's answer) such that it does not work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your `input` to contain a custom template like this:

```
<input name="states" id="states" type="text" 
       typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"
       placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" 
       typeahead="state.Index as state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
       class="form-control">
```

where the template looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
    <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label.Index | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span> - 
    <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label.Value | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>   
  </a>
</script>
```

Note that I have used the `States` as you provided so I hope the custom template makes sense.

Here's a [**forked codepen**](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/mmPjKa?editors=1010) that should behave like you want. I have a `pre` displaying the `ng-model` below it which contains only the number (say `4`) and not whole `4 - <State>`

**EDIT**: Or even better, you can still display state name in the `input` and use just the index (by `selected.Index`). [Sample codepen](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/QvNBPy?editors=1010) for that.

Comment: Thank you @tanmay for your response. Your suggestion shows entries correctly and returns the index correctly, but it does not allow using  combination of index and value. See? I need that it should also be possible to start typing the **Index** part, so that if I type **1** the list will open with entries Alabama, Georgia, Hawaii,...,Illinois.

Comment: I took your example (forked codepen) AS-IS (or so I believe) and it still does not work for me. I EDITed my question and added the source HTML and JS. Would much appreciate if you could take a look and let me know how could I wrongly copy it.

Comment: could you have a brief look at the edit I made to my initial question? I took the code you made AS-IS and it is not working for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: @FDavidov if it works on codepen, there might be some tiny mistake while copying maybe.. I can't help it if it's not reproducible on codepen or some plunker. Maybe start from scratch as per the codepen, see what you missed. Or if that doesn't work, ask a seperate question with related code so that if I can't find what's wrong, at least someone else will

Comment: @tanman thanks for your response. I'll try to compare the code in your codepen and the one I'm checking, though I **literally** copy-pasted it AS-IS, no changes at all. This is what puzzles me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just check both the HTMLs and the JSs. Identical. How can I see the links to the AngularJS (and other) libs? Perhaps, the issue is with the version I'm using (v1.4.0-rc.1).

Comment: @FDavidov ooh! That's rare.. Anyway, next time start with versions.. Good luck :)